# Is there any thread-safety bugs in such code?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I have a singleton Service implementaion class using Enum in my java web applcaition. It start once at application start and shutdown when applcaition was undeployed. and It provide some service method to client:

```
public enum SingletonService{
   INSTANCE;
  private boolean isStarted;

  public synchronized void start(){
     if(!isStarted){
         // do initialization stuff
         isStarted = true;
     }
  }

  public void stop(){
      checkStarted();
      // do stop jobs
      isStarted = false;
  }

 private synchronized void checkStarted(){
    if(!isStarted)
       throw new RuntimeException("SingletonService is not ready");
 }

  public void service(){
      checkStarted();
      // do service job
  }

}
```

Threading is a bit hard for me, I am worrying that I missed tricky bugs in my code. Is that necessary to make `start` and `checkStarted` synchronized?  Please tell me any bad thing in such code. I also want to know If there is a common pattern for doing such thing in java?

Comment: Threading is hard, even for smart programs.  You need to guard access to shared, mutable data.  You only have one shared data member.  You've synchronized all methods but one.  I'd synchronize service, too.

Comment: @duffymo I invoked checkStarted in service, is that not enough?

Comment: @WestFarmer there is no need to sync service as service calls checkStarted method which is a synced method. This class is thread safe even though it's not standard practice to implement Singleton pattern.

Comment: Don't know.  Be safe - keystrokes are cheap.  Type the keyword.  But do reconsider the Singleton.  That's a crime against humanity.

Comment: stop() is problematic too. Just after checkStarted() is executed, another thread could be calling start(). Then, back to the thread in stop(), it would set isStarted to false even though it was just started. Perhaps it's ok according to "your design", stop() would stop a Thread that was not started at the begining of the method (but was started during the execution)

Answer (score 2):

Code is thread-safe when it is guaranteed to behave as expected when used from multiple threads at once. Therefore it's hard to judge whether this particular code is thread-safe not knowing what it's expected behavior is. But I'll try and guess. I guess, that you expected, among others, that if `checkStarted()` called from `INSTANCE.service()` does not throw an exception, than the `service()` method may proceed safe in an assumption that your singleton will not get stopped before `service()` completes it's execution. With this assumption the answer is: your code is not thread-safe, you should, for example, add `synchronize` to both `stop` and `service` methods. You can then get rid of `synchronized` on `checkStarted`, as mentioned by @Guarava Agarwal's answer.

To see this, consider two threads. Thread A calls `INSTANCE.start()` followed by `INSTANCE.stop()` and thread B calls `INSTANCE.service()`. The following sequence of executions is not prohibited by your current synchronization:

1. Thread A executes `INSTANCE.start()`. `isStarted` is set to `true`.
2. Thread A enters `INSTANCE.stop()` and executes `INSTANCE.checkStarted()` (no exception thrown).
3. Thread B enters `INSTANCE.service()` and executes `INSTANCE.checkStarted()` (again, no exception thrown).
4. Thread A completes `INSTANCE.stop()`, setting `isStarted` to `false`.
5. Thread B proceeds with it's service job, with singleton already stopped, against our initial assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Two comments with reasons:

1. checkStarted is declared private. It's not changing state of service. It don't need to be declared synchronized if point#2 is addressed.
2. stop is public, it's changing state of service. it should be declared synchronized instead. Two threads accessing stop/start at the same time should access isStarted in synchronized way.

   ```
   public enum SingletonService{
    INSTANCE;
   private boolean isStarted;

   public synchronized void start(){
    if(!isStarted){
        // do initialization stuff
        isStarted = true;
    }
   }

   public synchronized void stop(){
     checkStarted();
     // do stop jobs
     isStarted = false;
   }

    private void checkStarted(){
     if(!isStarted)
         throw new RuntimeException("SingletonService is not ready");
    }

   public void service(){
     checkStarted();
      // do service job
   }

   }
   ```